# React Native - Error navigating to child components

Tags: react-native

I am able to define the initial route(Home) and the app navigates to that route. Inside Home I am calling another component called BoxLists which is displayed  as expected. The issue I am having is when calling another component called StationOne from inside BoxLists.

I am getting the following error: uncaught error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigator.push'

So the question is: How can I navigate from BoxLists to StationOne?

Note: I am planning to navigate to additional components(StationOne, StationTwo, StationN+1) from BoxLists.

Here is the code although you can go to RNPlayground at https://rnplay.org/apps/rLB5HQ. Thanks!

```
class App extends React.Component {
 navigatorRenderScene(route,navigator){
 if (route.title == "Home")
  { 
   return( <Home navigator={navigator} /> ); 
  }
 if (route.title == "StationOne")
  { 
   return( <StationOne navigator={navigator} /> );  
  }
}

 render() {
  return (
   <Navigator
     initialRoute = {{ title: "Home" }}
     renderScene = {this.navigatorRenderScene.bind(this)}
   />
  );
 }
}

 class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (      
     <View style={{flex: 1}}>
       <View style={styles.header}>
         <Text style={styles.headerText}>AdView</Text>
       </View>
      <BoxLists author="station one" navigator={navigator} />
     </View>            
   );
  }
 }

 class BoxLists extends React.Component {
  _goToStation(){
    this.props.navigator.push({
     title: 'StationOne'
    });
  } 

  render() {
    return (
     <View>
       <Text>You are in BoxList. The passed prop is: {this.props.author}</Text>
         <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._goToStation.bind(this)}>
            <Text>Press here to go to StationOne</Text>
         </TouchableHighlight>
     </View>
   );
  }
 }

 class StationOne extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (      
     <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <Text> This is station one </Text>
     </View>            
    );
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (      
     <View style={{flex: 1}}>
       <View style={styles.header}>
         <Text style={styles.headerText}>AdView</Text>
       </View>
      <BoxLists author="station one" navigator={this.props.navigator} />
     </View>            
   );
  }
 }
```

You need to pass this.props.navigator for the BoxLists component as  shown above

Comment: This is it, it worked!  Why not navigator={navigator} as explained in docs?

Comment: If it was used inside renderNavigationScene as shown in the docs, navigator comes as a parameter to the function. When you pass to a component , it is in the props object for that component